# unexists request url can still response ajax success ,why?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

There is someting wrong with my jquery ajax function and php for response the requset.
the problem is ,when request url is not exists ,the response status is still 200;

ajax function like below

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "http://localhost/project/Show/async/",//  if this address is exists
            /**url: "http://localhost/project/Show/async-1/*",*/  //this is wrong address
            data:$dataJson,
            beforeSend: function(XMLHttpRequest){
                alert('send before');
            },
            cache:false,  
            success: function(data, textStatus){
                alert(success);
            },
            error : function() {    
                alert("sorry , error！"); 

            },
            complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus){
                //HideLoading();
            },
        });
```

php code is simple :

```
      $response = self::parse2String($_REQUEST);
      var_dump($response);
```

**the response of status /async   and  /async-1 both 200**

need u help!

Comment: do you have some rewrite rule that redirects nonexistent urls to like index.php or something similar?

Comment: @PatrickEvans  no, the project buide with zend ,if the controller or action is not right ,it won't work i think

Comment: do you get a 404 page/error when you have your browser directly go to the `/async-1` url?

Comment: I will levae early to catch the train,if u have some idea ,I'll vote up next week ,thank u!

Comment: @PatrickEvans have no 404 page , just directly go to /async-1